# Como diminuir a guia aberta no Visual Code e mostrar seta de navegação entre as guias?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Como diminuir a guia aberta no Visual Code e mostrar seta de navegação entre as guias?

No caso, quero diminuir o tamanho da guia de cada arquivo aberto, e/ou quando eu abrir vários arquivos, conseguir visualizar com alguma seta, igual tem no Visual Studio. Teria como?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que não tem como. Dei uma olhada superficial sobre a [API de extensões de temas](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/theming) do VSCode e encontrei endpoints para trocar os ícones, cores, criar arvores de exibição analítica mas alterar o tamanho da aba da guia de código não encontrei.

Comment: Vi que teve voto para fechar a pergunta. Não faz sentido, sendo que ela se encaixa perfeitamente na opção: "ferramentas comuns entre programadores, quando aplicadas no desenvolvimento de software". Quando ocorrer votos assim, a pessoa poderia procurar entender mais a comunidade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É possível configurar o tamanho dos separadores para uma de duas opções:

- `fit` - O separador ocupa o tamanho necessário para o nome ser visível
- `shrink` - Os separadores são ajustados em tamanho de forma a que todos sejam visíveis

Esta configuração é feita em File > Preferences > Settings:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois no topo dos settings escreva `tabSizing` para aceder ao *setting* correto e escolha `shrink`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja um exemplo com `fit` que é o valor por defeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E um exemplo com `shrink`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que o meu exemplo foi forçado e todos os arquivos tem o mesmo nome, logo fica difícil de perceber em qual a pessoa está. Num exemplo mais real será mais evidente.

Quanto às setas para navegar entre separadores eu desconheço tal opção e suspeito que não exista, mas pode sempre usar atalhos. Em windows e linux pode usar:

- Ctrl + Tab para avançar para o próximo separador
- Ctrl + Shift + Tab para ir para o separador anterior

Comment: É uma opção tb, boa Isac!

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Obrigada Isac.

Answer (score 3):

No guia da interface do usuário não tem nada sobre navegar por setas pelas Tabs, talvez isso tenha existido em alguma versão anterior, mas não existe mais, pelo menos não na documentação oficial como vc pode consultar aqui https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_tabs

No entanto aqui está um workaround, vc pode clicar no ícone de `...` bem na direita, no final do *Tab Groups*, lá tem a opção de **Show Opened Editors**, assim vai abrir um `dropdown` com todos os arquivos que estão abertos no momento.

Vc tb pode usar os atalhos de teclado para navegar rapidamente entre as Tabs. Aqui está a lista completa dos atalhos https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_keyboard-shortcuts 
*(consulte o atalho correto para o seu sistema operacional!)*

- `⌥⌘→ vai para tab da direita`
- `⌥⌘← vai para tab da esquerda`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]